# Things to keep in mind while architecting high volume traffic centered web site

Tags: web

I have this question. If I am designing a web site which is expected to have high-traffic, then what are the things I should keep in mind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about your database management.
Build your database tables, and links between tables keeping in mind that you do not want to search / load useless things.

Answer (score 0):

Once the site is working, I would optimise it as much as possible. Tools like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) make it easy to analyse a page and pinpoint bottlenecks and places for improvements.

Also for a high volume site, I think that you definitely want to use a content delivery network. There are lots of options, including [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com). Using a CDN will reduce the load on your server by 60-80%, it will make the site faster and it will cost you hardly anything.

Unless there is a specific reason why it's not a good fit for your site, you can't go wrong!

Good luck!